# Trying to get a horizontal scrollable website to work on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The website is working fine on normal browsers e.g. Opera, Firefox, Chrome, etc. It is scrolled on pc by dragging the mouse or using the standard horizontal scrollbar.

**The problem starts on mobile:**
I was trying to get it to work for quite a while. The first idea was using the default `touch-action: pan-x;` which was working, except for the elements containing `position: fixed;` in their style. They were behaving weirdly (while dragging right - they were showing fine, but when dragging left - they were hiding). I tried changing the `position` property to `absolute` and then setting it to the `window.scrollLeft` or `$(window).scrollLeft()` which both returned wrong values (seems like panning is not changing the `scrollLeft` value correctly, why?) So I thought that using JQuery's `scrollLeft()` would be easier to use.

Next thing I tried was using the same code I used for desktop browsers. I used `($(window).scrollLeft(xPosition)` and while on PCs it's working, on mobile it's stopping at `1385 pixels` on Opera's emulator and 1826 on Firefox's emulator (`body` width is set to `2824.81px`)

Function I'm using to scroll:

```
var updateScrollPos = function (x) { // scroll by x
    if (($(window).scrollLeft() + (x + $(window).width()) > maxScroll)) {
        $(window).scrollLeft(maxScroll - $(window).width());
    }
    else {
        $(window).scrollLeft($(window).scrollLeft() + x);
    }
    console.log(x);
    console.log($(window).scrollLeft());
}
```

and the maxScroll is based on the image width:
`maxScroll = $('.scrollview img').width();`

[maxScroll and scrollLeft values in Opera debug screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOE1I.png)

All I need is to know if there's a function that returns the `pan-x position` or why my updateScrollPos is not working correctly on mobile.

It's my first post so I'm sorry if I missed any important informations and thank you in advance!